# Is there a possibility to change the textfont of a textview only in xml-Code?

Tags: android, eclipse, fonts, textview

It would be much easier and faster if I only need to edit the XML-Code and not the Java-Code...

Comment: There are only four basic fonts you can use in XML. Also I am downvoting your question, because it does not show any research effort.

Comment: No. See Commonsware's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562408/set-specific-font-in-a-styles-xml)

Comment: Check this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little googling goes a long way. Have a look at this library: https://github.com/danh32/Fontify. It'll allow you to specify fonts through xml.